# Jenkins Approval as Input and its usage in other stages

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to create a approval stage at very beginning of my pipeline, on the basis of that input, rest of the stages will either be executed or skipped.

in my case, i am not able to use them on other stages. what could be the reason . I need to check value as Approved.  please suggest

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        string(name: 'Localities', defaultValue: '', description: 'Enter Country Name')
        string(name: 'name', defaultValue: '', description: 'Enter  Name')
        string(name: 'HOST', defaultValue: '', description: 'Enter Host Name')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Approval') {
            steps {
                script {
                    emailext body: "Localities : ${Localities} \n name : ${name} \n Click this link to approve and run the executor job: ${env.BUILD_URL}console",
                             subject: "Job Approval: Supplier Delete with build #${currentBuild.number}",
                             to: 'user1'
                   timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') {
                env.approvalStatus= input message: 'You want to approve this build? ', ok: 'Submit', parameters: [choice(choices: ['Approved', 'Rejected'], name: 'ApprovalStatus')], submitter: 'user1,user2', submitterParameter: 'approverID'
                   }
                }
                echo "Approval status: ${env.approvalStatus}"
                //##prints Approval status: {approverID=user1, ApprovalStatus=Approved}
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            when {
                expression { env.approvalStatus == 'Approved' }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'echo "Building..."'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            when {
                expression { env.approvalStatus == 'Approved' }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'echo "Deploying..."'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

even if i select and submit Approved. all my stages are getting skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the updated Pipeline. Seems your input is returning a HashMap, hence save the return map as is by removing the env prefix then extract the Input parameter from the HashMap like `approvalStatus["ApprovalStatus"]`

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Approval') {
            steps {
                script {
                   timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') {
                        approvalStatus = input message: 'You want to approve this build? ', ok: 'Submit', parameters: [choice(choices: ['Approved', 'Rejected'], name: 'ApprovalStatus')], submitter: 'user1,user2', submitterParameter: 'approverID'
                   }
                }
                echo "Approval status: ${approvalStatus}"
                //##prints Approval status: {approverID=user1, ApprovalStatus=Approved}
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            when {
                expression { approvalStatus["ApprovalStatus"] == 'Approved' }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'echo "Building..."'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            when {
                expression { approvalStatus["ApprovalStatus"] == 'Approved' }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'echo "Deploying..."'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I actually tried these steps but even if i approved my input , all the stages were getting skipped. so i finally decided to use env variable and use contains() to check if "Approved" substring exists in env.approvalStatus.

Comment: @deewreck I minified the Pipeline, if you copy the shared Pipeline as-is does it work? It works fine for me.